# MySQL query works in phpmyadmin but not through php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Any ideas would help, I have been on this for a while now and just can't figure out what is wrong.

Problem: query works fine until I added in the multiple word search which you can see bolded below. However, I echoed the sql query and then pasted in phpmyadmin and it worked perfectly but through the php it results with 0 records. It doesn't make any sense and I can't figure out what could be causing a result of 0.

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT c.id 
    FROM 
        carpets AS c 
        INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r1 ON c.id = r1.carpet_id 
        INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r2 ON c.id = r2.carpet_id
        INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r3 ON c.id = r3.carpet_id
    WHERE 
        c.active = '1' 



        AND ((c.title LIKE '%north tabriz%') OR **(c.title LIKE '%north%') OR (c.title LIKE '%tabriz%')** OR (c.item_no LIKE '%north tabriz%') OR **(c.item_no LIKE '%north%') OR (c.item_no LIKE '%tabriz%')** OR (c.pattern LIKE '%north tabriz%') OR **(c.pattern LIKE '%north%') OR (c.pattern LIKE '%tabriz%')** OR (c.period LIKE '%north tabriz%') OR **(c.period LIKE '%north%') OR (c.period LIKE '%tabriz%')** OR (c.country LIKE '%north tabriz%') **OR (c.country LIKE '%north%') OR (c.country LIKE '%tabriz%')**)

        AND (c.width_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '22') 
        AND (c.width_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
        AND (c.height_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '49') 
        AND (c.height_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
    ORDER BY 
        c.item_no


id  int(11) NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
active  int(11) NO      NULL    
title   varchar(250)    NO      NULL    
item_no     varchar(250)    NO      NULL    
country     varchar(250)    NO      NULL    
period  varchar(250)    NO      NULL    
pattern     varchar(250)    NO      NULL    
price   float   NO      NULL    
web_special     float   NO      NULL    
notes   text    NO      NULL    
width_feet  int(11) NO      NULL    
width_inches    int(11) NO      NULL    
height_feet     int(11) NO      NULL    
height_inches   int(11) NO      NULL    
restrict    int(11) NO      NULL    
views_amount    int(11) NO      NULL    
last_modified   datetime    NO      NULL    
modified_by     int(11) NO      NULL
```

Comment: Does any other easier statement work in your context? (Like SELECT * FROM carpets)

Comment: It would be helpful to see your table schemas and the error from mysql.

Comment: yes they do as well as if the areas that are surrounded by ** are removed then it works just fine on the front end....however when i add those sections in there on the front end it does not work and on the backend (phpmyadmin) it does

Comment: If the same query returns different results from different context, my first check would be if I really run it against the same database?

Comment: i know in PHP you can't have multiple queries to mysql seperated by ; so i am wondering if it could be the same for ** will get back here if i find something more clear

Comment: Are you sure that c.item_no is a text field? Sounds more like a number where you can't use like '%text%'

Comment: that is the thing there is no error returned

Comment: have you tried the MATCH ... AGAINST for your query instead?

Comment: just to clarify ** was added to the query just for here to show what was added

Comment: it might be a stupid idea but you can check if you have a space character at the end of each line.

Comment: at djot i fixed it to check for number values still no change

Comment: if i put in a single word it works but it is when i do multiple words it doesn't hence the extra check on there of separating the search by spaces and adding in another like clause to accommodate for each word

Comment: if anyone would like to see it with the sql outputted you can go to: http://50.28.19.26/search.php and type in the top search bar the word 'north' and it will bring up the results right however when you type in 'north tabriz' it should bring up all that have north and all that have tabriz

Comment: You could get a better help if you will show us the structure of `carpets` table (run `describe carpets` and add the output here) and write this `c.title LIKE '%north tabriz%'` as `c.title LIKE '%north%tabriz%'` not as (c.title LIKE '%north%') OR (c.title LIKE '%tabriz%')

Comment: id  int(11) NO  PRI  NULL auto_increment
active  int(11) NO   NULL 
title  varchar(250) NO   NULL 
item_no  varchar(250) NO   NULL 
country  varchar(250) NO   NULL 
period  varchar(250) NO   NULL 
pattern  varchar(250) NO   NULL 
price  float NO   NULL 
web_special  float NO   NULL 
notes  text NO   NULL 
width_feet  int(11) NO   NULL 
width_inches  int(11) NO   NULL 
height_feet  int(11) NO   NULL 
height_inches  int(11) NO   NULL 
restrict  int(11) NO   NULL 
views_amount  int(11) NO   NULL 
last_modified  datetime NO   NULL 
modified_by  int(11) NO   NULL

Comment: there you go i added it above

Comment: the only thing that would really help you is to take little steps and to try your query in your code first only with `c.active = '1' AND c.title LIKE '%north%tabriz%'`, and then if everything is OK you run it with `c.active = '1' AND (c.title LIKE '%north%tabriz%' OR c.item_no LIKE '%north%tabriz%')` and so on...

Comment: you can remove the `c.title LIKE '%north tabriz%'`, because it is equivalent to `c.title LIKE '%north%'`, which counterfeits it.

Comment: This query is VERY EXPENSIVE.  You should consider re-normalizing your data.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code? That's what seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT c.id 
FROM 
    carpets AS c 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r1 ON c.id = r1.carpet_id 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r2 ON c.id = r2.carpet_id
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r3 ON c.id = r3.carpet_id
WHERE 
    c.active = '1' 

    AND ((c.title LIKE '%north%')
   OR (c.title LIKE '%tabriz%')
   OR (c.item_no LIKE '%north%')
   OR (c.item_no LIKE '%tabriz%')
   OR (c.pattern LIKE '%north%')
   OR (c.pattern LIKE '%tabriz%')
   OR (c.period LIKE '%north%')
   OR (c.period LIKE '%tabriz%') 
   OR (c.country LIKE '%north%')
   OR (c.country LIKE '%tabriz%'))

    AND (c.width_feet BETWEEN 0 AND 22) 
    AND (c.width_inches BETWEEN 0 AND 11) 
    AND (c.height_feet BETWEEN 0 AND 49) 
    AND (c.height_inches BETWEEN 0 AND 11) 
ORDER BY 
    c.item_no
```

I dropped the "LIKE '%north tabriz%'" sections because they were redundant, since if it matched "north tabriz" alone, then  "north" and "tabriz" would also be true.

Also, I took the single quotes away that were surrounding the numbers in the between clauses.

Can't reproduce the tables to test it since you only have 1 table shown, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Pay close attention to how you use quotes in PHP also. For SQL queries with a where clause specifically it can be an issue since the where clause need to say WHERE x = 'value' in Single quotes. Therefore make sure your overall SQL string uses Double quotes. Also, PHP variables in single quotes will not be evaluated, so if you are basing a where clause on a PHP variable you need to wrap that variable in Single quotes before using it in the SQL statement. I hope all of that made sense, I got stuck on this issue for 2 days when I started learning PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

try simple queries first ( to test connection)
if they dont work look into database host, username , password (they might be wrongly input)

Once you are sure of the db connection , try using multi query function in php, remove needless spacing , run the query in a for loop or multiple steps

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely not the query but an error in your PHP code somewhere. Can you post you PHP code for us to take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this problem, it happens only when there is any problem with connections or  or your query. Please print your query and see how it prints. In query you must be using `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle ("") correctly in your php code. If your query works fine in phpMyAdmin then it should work with in your php code too. Or there could be some error in your database connection. Make sure you are selecting correct database of your desired table.